# Windows Phone 7 Navigation Service URI?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, navigationservice

In my project, I have created a separate folder called "Pages" for storing all pages except the main page. I wish to navigate to one of these pages from the main page. How do i do it? I've had no luck with:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/Page1.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

I'm getting a null reference exception each time.thanks in advance!
Also is there any way i can navigate using the pages constructor instead like in WPF?

Comment: where are you calling that code?

Comment: Don't try and Navigate from within the constructor, which is what can cause the Null Reference Exception to be thrown. Is that what you're doing? Also, what you mean you want to navigate using the page's constructor?

Comment: ^^Thanks that did it,im still getting used to the subtle differences between WPF and WP7.What i meant with navigating using the pages constructor is that,WPF allows you to do the following->'this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());'

Answer (score 2):

`NavigationService` is specific to a page. If you are trying to invoke it from outside one, you will generally get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: No,i was trying to call it from within the constructor of the main page to make up for uncompleted navigation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the OnNavigateTo() event and perform page navigation from there. You don't get null exception over there.

This event is fired just after the constructor is loaded and hence is ideal place if you want to check for some condition and perform navigation before the page is loaded completely.

Also, there is another called "OnNavigateFrom()" which occurs when you exit the page.

Hope that helps.